# ESP32 give strange behavior

Tags: esp32

My ESP32 Devkit V1 board is not detected by computer through USB, the LED Power is turn off. The led will turn on when i press "EN" button and off when i dont press it.

However,also the LED power is ON when i give 3v3 external powersupply with connected to 3v3 pin then i still can uploading program through USB.
I have uploading blink program and running fine.

What just did i do before this problem come?
I was uploading with Arduino IDE with wrong board in arduino board manager. I didnt focus, it was `MH ET ESP32 DEVKIT` while i should have chose `DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1` in board manager.

Even thought i was wrong board, the program still successfully uploaded with both of board option (wrong board and true board) in board manager.

I dont understand how to troubleshoot this, im not sure the USB is problem.

Comment: Try another USB cable

Answer (score 0):

Solved

I was checking it with volt meter, the VIN PIN was about half of VCC while it should be near VCC of USB power supply.
So i just solder a point from board circuit which showed 5v in voltmeter then connect it (solder) to the VIN.

Then they are work fine.